# Lightbox Not Pulling from Stylesheet

Tags: lightbox

So, the lightbox works on my [page](http://www.aliceskids.org/kidswehelp2.html) but it doesn't respond to any changes made in the stylesheet file, lightbox.css. Yet, when I remove reference to the file, the lightbox stops working, so it's clearly being called to.

In the page's code, the stylesheet is being called with:

```
    <link href="../css_javascript/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the jquery is being called with:

```
    <script src="../css_javascript/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

Truly have no idea what to do from here. I'm really just trying to get rid of the Image # count, and calling to lightbox.option in the page's code doesn't work either.

Not sure what information is best needed to put me on a solution path.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any duplicate selectors in your lightbox.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the "image 1 of 4" text, it is not done in the CSS but in the javascript options for Lightbox. 
Add this to your page after `<script src="../css_javascript/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>`:

```
<script>
lightbox.option({
  'showImageNumberLabel': false
})
</script>
```

Also, your Lightbox.css file is not loading the navigation images, the loading  and close images used by the light box.

```
body:after {content: url(../images/close.png) url(../images/loading.gif) url(../images/prev.png) url(../images/next.png);
  display: none;
}
```

They need to be in a folder, images, one level up from your "css_javascript" folder.

Comment: Appreciate your help on that first part, I'll give it a shot!

As for the 2nd suggestion, just to make sure I understand, the images folder should be within the css_javascript folder? Or the other way around?

Comment: Your CSS file is here: `http://www.aliceskids.org/css_javascript/lightbox.css ` and the images (close.png, loading.gif, prev.png, next.png) need to be in a folder called _images_, one level up from _css_javascript_, like this `http://www.aliceskids.org/images/`. That's what the _../_ means in the CSS.

Comment: Oh, duh, I see what you mean. Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answered your question, appreciate you marking it as answered.